# This AWS CLI bash script works, but how to limit it to delete only log files on top level?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't write many bash scripts, especially with AWS, so could use some help.

A results of turning-on AWS S3 Logging with Versioning at the same time and it ended-up generating over 70,000 log files (joy), then trying to deleting only sets a delete marker file.

The bash shell script below works great to delete all versions of S3 objects/files and delete markers in the given bucket.

Problem is, I need to keep the 25 GB of real/legit files, but need to delete the 70,000 versioned log files with delete markers that got mixed-in.

This doesn't do anything anymore, because they're versioned and already have delete markers:
*aws s3 rm s3://MYBUCKETNAME/ --exclude "*" --include "2020-*"*

Don't think any kind of LifeCycle expiration stuff will work, because valid files are mixed-in with valid files, before and afterwards, only thing I can think of that could work is to delete files that begin with "2020-" (BUT, only on the top level, NOT recursively.)

So, I'm looking to modify script below to only delete files that begin with "2020-" (BUT, only on the top level), which is all the logs files that accidentally got created on the S3 container.

2020-01-25-07-33-44-DAC13CC9B600B11A
2020-01-25-07-33-46-59F44EEC6F93E8C7
2020-01-25-07-33-47-786A5091CABF6912
...etc...

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #USAGE: sh delete_all_object_versions.sh MYBUCKETNAME

    bucket=$1

    set -e

    echo "Removing all versions from $bucket"

    versions=`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket |jq '.Versions'`
    markers=`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket |jq '.DeleteMarkers'`

    echo "removing files"
    for version in $(echo "${versions}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
        version=$(echo ${version} | base64 --decode)

        key=`echo $version | jq -r .Key`
        versionId=`echo $version | jq -r .VersionId `
        cmd="aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucket --key $key --version-id $versionId"
        echo $cmd
        $cmd
    done

    echo "removing delete markers"
    for marker in $(echo "${markers}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
        marker=$(echo ${marker} | base64 --decode)

        key=`echo $marker | jq -r .Key`
        versionId=`echo $marker | jq -r .VersionId `
        cmd="aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucket --key $key --version-id $versionId"
        echo $cmd
        $cmd
    done
```

Comment: You could exclude any objects with a slash (`/`) in the Key, since they would be in sub-directories. Also, make sure that `2020-` is at the start of the name, to avoid deleting potentially wrong objects.

Comment: Thank you John, appreciate the comment and it helped me get onto the right track of figuring out a solution. Weird that someone downvoted though... Anyway, will post my solution and hopefully, it will help others who turn-on AWS S3 logging along with versioning and accidentally end-up with a ton of txt log files like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to deleted the 85,000 log files that were deleted (with delete markers), after reading John's helpful comment, using a prefix to ensure that the objects start with '2020-'.

This removed only the log files starting with '2020-' on the root level of the S3 container and did NOT go into subfolders like 'mp3/2020-', so it left the valid files that started with year dates.

```
versions=`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket --prefix '2020-' |jq '.Versions'`
markers=`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket --prefix '2020-' |jq '.DeleteMarkers'`
```

Below, is the final bash script that I ran on my Mac with AWS CLI S3API...

```
#!/bin/bash

#USAGE: sh delete_all_object_versions.sh BUCKETNAME
#TEST:  aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --prefix '2020-'

bucket=$1

set -e

echo "Removing all versions from $bucket"

versions=`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket --prefix '2020-' |jq '.Versions'`
markers=`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket --prefix '2020-' |jq '.DeleteMarkers'`

echo "removing files"
for version in $(echo "${versions}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do 
    version=$(echo ${version} | base64 --decode)

    key=`echo $version | jq -r .Key`
    versionId=`echo $version | jq -r .VersionId `
    cmd="aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucket --key $key --version-id $versionId"
    echo $cmd
    $cmd
done

echo "removing delete markers"
for marker in $(echo "${markers}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do 
    marker=$(echo ${marker} | base64 --decode)

    key=`echo $marker | jq -r .Key`
    versionId=`echo $marker | jq -r .VersionId `
    cmd="aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucket --key $key --version-id $versionId"
    echo $cmd
    $cmd
done
```

Comment: FYI, to extract values from AWS CLI output, instead of `jq` you can [Filter the Output with the --query Option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter), combined with `--output text`.

Comment: Thanks John, great tip, didn't know about that way to extract and filter, will have to experiment with that soon.

Comment: It uses something called [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/examples.html), which is a very powerful way of filtering the output. (The author, James, works on the AWS CLI team!)